# Use react-autolink+react-emoji together (give me error r.split)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react...I'm trying to use react-autolink component together with react-emoji component.

The problem is that when I do:

```
{@autolink(@emojify(@props.message.body))}
```

It give me this error: Uncaught TypeError: r.split is not a function

Why ? instead if I use only:

```
@emojify(@props.message.body)
```

Or

```
@autolink(@props.message.body)
```

It works...

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Emojify returns a React element, which, of course does not have a split function which in turn React Autolink will fail.

Comment: @limelights ok but so how I can use both ? I've also tried to do something like this: `text_with_emoji = @emojify(@props.message.body)`and then done `@autolink(text_with_emoji)` - but ofc it doesn't work...how I should do ? thanks.

Comment: Why just not wrap it yourself and save yourself the hassle?

Comment: @limelights what do you mean ? you mean do it before I save in db ??

Comment: @Riccardo, I have to agree with @limelights; you are better off rewriting or wrapping them as components or really they should just be left as utility functions.  The way it uses mixins to add those utility functions that return arrays of React elements that is irrelevant to the current this component; the implementation could be done better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate through the array of React elements and autolink the strings (text that hasn't been transformed yet).

```
@autolink(@props.message.body).map(el => {
  if( typeof el === "string" ) return @emojify(el); else return el;
});
```

Comment: Ok now it works(I've done some changes for syntax)...but I'm not sure that this is the best way for do it :S seems weird because they suggest to use the plugins together!!!

Comment: @Riccardo IMHO the "best" way would be to rewrite the components or just modify them so that they are just utility functions in a module, both of which should be simple to do.  As far as using the functions as is, this would be how it is implemented in its current form.